# Want to show animation while datagridview is filling with data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

Hello People im filling datagrid when on forms load event this way:

```
 private void Inventory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AcidDBDataContext db = new AcidDBDataContext();

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = db.GetProducts.ToList();

        dgvInventory.DataSource = bs;
        ProductBindingNavigator.BindingSource = bs;

        ShowtoolStripButton2.Visible = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgvInventory.Columns)
        {
            c.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 12.0F, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

    }
```

its working fine but there is one problem i needs few second and my form is freezing. How i can do while my datagrid is filling show loading animation and when grid will be filled hide animation

Im using C# winForms.
THanks a lot

Comment: What takes the majority of the time, extracting the results from the database or displaying them?

Comment: yes. executing query. i have local database yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into BackgroundWorkerThreads.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx

I used them quite a bit while retrieving data. I would display a waiting bar, call the DoWork event where data is retrieved into a dataset (for us, this usually took longer than attaching said data to the grid), then in the RunWorkerCompleted event I attached the data to the grid and hid the waiting bar. The app still froze for a few seconds, but not nearly as long.

Here's some sample code. Basically, lock fields that could cause `RefreshInventory` to be called again (but since you're loading at startup maybe that doesn't apply to you). Then retrieve the data in the thread and attach it when the thread is done.

```
public void RefreshInventory()
{
    // Lock any fields you want to lock during the update process
    // Display some kind of waiting or progress bar
    if (!bkgdWrkInventory.IsBusy)
        bkgdWrkInventory.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bkgdWrkInventory_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var db = new AcidDBDataContext();
    e.Result = db.GetProducts.ToList();
}

private void bkgdWrkInventory_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)  // Check for errors
    {
        dgvInventory.DataSource = (List<Product>)e.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        // Show the error to the user
    }

    // Hide the waiting indicator
    // Unlock the fields
}
```