# How can I use a ProgressBar to show the status of loading data into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, odbc

I am trying to load a large amount of data (~1gb) into a data table from a DBF file using ODBC. This part works, I can load the data fine.

However, since it takes some time, I would like to display a progress bar indicating the loading status.

Here is the code:

```
public void loadMRP(ref Dictionary<string, string> parts)
{
    parts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=c:\\M.DBF;Exclusive=No; NULL=NO;Collate=Machine;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;DELETED=NO;");
    conn.Open();

    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM c:\M.DBF";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();

    using (DataTableReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader())
    {
        int numParts = dt.Rows.Count;
        int c = 0;
        do
        {
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty DataTableReader");
            }
            else
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!parts.ContainsKey(reader[2].ToString().Trim()))
                        parts.Add(reader[2].ToString().Trim(), reader[9].ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            c++;
            progBar.Value = 100*(c / numParts);
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

I thought this would increment progBar as the Dictionary is populated, but the progBar value remains at 0 for the duration of loading.

I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish this, but I don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you want to load 1GIG of data into a `Dictionary<string, string>` ? I would construct a query that pulls back partial data based on some filtering as well as specify in the select statement how many rows for example `TOP 10000 rows` this is not very efficient way to retrieve and populate data, your application would take very long not to mention would have a memory exception

Comment: There are many post on here about this [heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531987/how-do-i-display-a-progress-bar-while-loading-a-datatable-to-datagridview) a post with two examples