# Add a progress bar while the a table is being load it to the DataGridView In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need some help on adding a progress bar while the datagridview is being load it. I already have my code that loads the datagridview but as we know the loading takes time to finish loading depending of the records. So, I would like to add a progress bar loading and a label having a the count from 1 to 100 to complete.

I know there is a way using the background work handle event, but not sure how that make it work.  I would like something simple but can do the work I need.

my code works great fills the datagridview as I want. but I need to add the progress bar while loading the datagridview.

change the code please review and let me know if I missed something.

So I made the changes and seems to work now, but there is an issue the progress bar does not work immediately takes a few seconds and then I can see the progress bar to move to 100%. Why it does that?

second issue after loading the datagridview the progress bar color goes away after I click the message  MessageBox.Show("Successful Completion.");

here is a test image after my combo box select the value we want and display the datagridview

### [image]

here I made the new changes to the program, but for some reason after I select the combobox the datagridview populates correctly but then I try again sometimes it fails and gives me this error
[image]

```
    namespace DatagridViewProgressBar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //datagridview, bindingsource, data_apapter global objects variables
        private DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        //class objects
        Databases lemars = new Databases();
        Databases schuyler = new Databases();
        Databases detroitlakeskc = new Databases();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // To report progress from the background worker we set this property
            dbWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            dbWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(dbWorker_DoWork);
            dbWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(dbWorker_ProgressChanged);
            dbWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(dbWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            dbWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            dbWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        }

        private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox_Database_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox_Database.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LeMars21St")
            {

                if (dbWorker.IsBusy != true)
                {
                    dbWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                }            
            }
        }



        private void GetTableToDataGridView()
        {
            //prgBar_DataGridViewLoading
            DatabaseColumns Obj = new DatabaseColumns();
            String SqlcmdString = @"SELECT invoice, shipment, Project, invoiceDateTB, CreatedDate, typeName, exportedDate, statusName, total, import_status, Time_Completed, ERROR_DESCRIPTION FROM dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus";
            SqlDataReader reader;
            int progress;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(lemars._LeMarsConnectionString))
            {
                reader = null;
                SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(SqlcmdString, conn);
                conn.Open();
                reader = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        dt.Load(reader);

                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Obj.Invoice = dt.Rows[i]["invoice"].ToString();
                            Obj.Shipment = dt.Rows[i]["shipment"].ToString();
                            Obj.Project = dt.Rows[i]["Project"].ToString();
                            Obj.InvoiceDateTB = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["invoiceDateTB"]);
                            Obj.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["CreatedDate"]);
                            Obj.TypeName = dt.Rows[i]["typeName"].ToString();
                            Obj.ExportedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["exportedDate"]);
                            Obj.StatusName = dt.Rows[i]["statusName"].ToString();
                            Obj.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["total"]);
                            Obj.ImportStatus = dt.Rows[i]["import_status"].ToString();
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"]))
                            {
                                Obj.TimeCompleted = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"]);
                            }
                            Obj.ErrorDescription = dt.Rows[i]["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

                            progress = i * 100 / dt.Rows.Count; 
                            dbWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }                     
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void dbWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetTableToDataGridView();
            dbWorker.ReportProgress(100);
        }

        private void dbWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar_GetTasks.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            // eg: Set your label text to the current value of the progress bar
            lbl_PercentageCount.Text = (progressBar_GetTasks.Value.ToString() + "%");         
        }

        private void dbWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = dt;

            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Process Cancelled.");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occurred: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successful Completion.");
            }

            //progressBar_GetTasks.Value = 0;
        }

        private void btn_CancelOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dbWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                dbWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377818/progressbar-for-loading-data-to-datagridview-using-datatable

Comment: First you __need__ to find out where the time is spent: During retrieval, in the loop or with binding? Without this all suggestions are just guesswork!

Comment: The solution I provided will move the process of retrieving the data from the DB into a different thread.

Comment: If you don't want the progress bar to go away at the end, then remove the line that is setting the value to 0. `progressBar_GetTasks.Value = 0`

Comment: Move the function call for GetTableToDataGridView() inside the function dbWorker_DoWork(). Currently everything except one progress update is happening in the main thread!

Comment: Declare a new variable: `int progress;`  Add two new lines inside your `for` loop: `progress = i * 100 / dt.rows.count;  dbWorker.ReportProgress(progress);`

Comment: I added the changes, but for some reason sometimes the datagridview populates correctly after selecting my combobox but sometimes it fails and gives me the error you can see above

Comment: The latest error is because you have not moved the `GetTableToDataGridView()` function call... you have copied it! In your event handler `comboBox_Database_SelectedIndexChanged`, remove the `GetTableToDataGridView()` line. Otherwise, you are starting a new thread to do the processing, as well as doing the processing on the main thread. Sometimes you will be lucky and the two processes will overlap. Sometimes you won't be so lucky and one of the processes will finish first and you will get an exception.

Comment: I understand that, but the what I need is that when the user select the combobox selection then populate the datagridview, if I remove it from the combobox event handler then the datagridview will not show? how can I fix that?

Comment: nevermind, you are correct, thanks bro for all YOUR HELP!!!!. learned alot. everything is working as it should I believe, if not I get back to you. thanks. @PeterAbolins.

Comment: @PeterAbolins,  I have one question. everything is working now. the only problem I see is that why the progress bar doesn't start right away when I select the combobox selection? takes like 5 seconds then starts 1 to 100% I would like it to start right away when i make the selection? do you know why is not starting right away?

Comment: I would need to see the code that is triggered when you make a change to the combobox selection. Although, it is possible that the 5 seconds is just process setup time. If the above image is indicative of the number of records in the result set (5 records), it is highly likely that you won't even see the progress bar moving - it will look like it simply goes straight to 100%, once it gets started.

Comment: @PeterAbolins, I added the most updated code above, as I said now the code works but the only issue is that the progress should trigger as soon as I select the value of the combobox but is not doing it, takes like 20 seconds to be exact after doing multiple tests. the user should be able to see the progress moving in progress as soon as they select the value of the combobox, but that part is not working as I would like, can you review the code to see what I can change to make this works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `SELECT *` is a bad idea, regardless of how many columns you have, or need. Explicitly stating which columns you want opens up possibilities for using indices and reduces maintainability issues with your code.

Secondly, your main question. I have done something similar recently, and can give some pointers. I am going not going to immediately apply this to your code-snippet, because I think that will complicate things.

**EDIT**

For thread safety purposes, the code inside `dbWorker_DoWork()` should not try to access form elements which were created in the main thread. There are obviously ways around this, and once you get to the `dbWorker_RunWorkerCompleted()` function, you are back in the main thread and you have full access to the necessary form elements.

**END EDIT**

1) Your form. You need a backgroundworker to do the work, as well as three callback functions to handle what is going on. A progress bar is assumed to be on the form as well (`System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar`).

```
...
using System.ComponentModel;
...
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker dbWorker;
    ...
    public YourForm()
    {
        ...
        dbWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        dbWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(dbWorker_DoWork);
        dbWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(dbWorker_ProgressChanged);
        dbWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(dbWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        dbWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        dbWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void dbWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is where you put your GetTableToDataGridView() code.
        // Add a line inside the loop, for reporting on progress:

        // dbWorker.ReportProgress((int)(currentIteration * 100 / totalIterations));

        // At the end of the process, set the progress bar to 100% (optional)
        dbWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    public void dbWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        // Here you can also do other things, which depend on the progress. 
        // eg: Set your label text to the current value of the progress bar.
    }

    public void dbWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Process Cancelled.");
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred: "+ e.Error.Message.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successful Completion.");
        }

        progressBar.Value = 0;
    } 
}
```

2) Starting the process (this could go in your form load function, or if you start the process manually, in an `OnClick` event):

```
...
if (!dbWorker.IsBusy)
{
    dbWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
...
```

3) Cancelling the process (if you have a button for cancelling, then this would go in the `OnClick` event code):

```
...
if (dbWorker.IsBusy)
{
    dbWorker.CancelAsync();
}
...
```

Comment: I made the changes to the program, please review above if I miss anything. also I added an error I am getting is an image

Comment: You need to move the assignment to the data grid, from the `DoWork` process, to the `RunWorkerCompleted` process. This can be done by say extending the scope of the dt object  (move the variable outside the function, so it is accessible by both the DoWork process and the RunWorkerCompleted process), and then populating dt in DoWork,  and populating the grid in RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: I made the changes above can you review and the image as well

Comment: If the above answer helped you with your initial question, maybe you can mark it as an answer?  Moving forward, a tip is to make errors work for you instead of against you: Google the error message when it appears. 9 times out of 10, the answer to your problem will be one of the first results returned.

Answer (score 0):

A couple obvious problems:

- Since you have the connection inside a `using` block, the explicit `conn.Close()` is unnecessary. The `using` mechanism will automatically close it even if an exception occurs. In fact, unless you have a need to handle exceptions at this level, you can remove the `try` block altogether.
- Never use `SELECT *`. You are retrieving a ton of data you don't need and this is probably why it's going slow in the first place.

To the meat of your question: `BackgroundWorker` is your friend!

I'm more familiar with doing data binding with WPF, so you'll need to do some legwork on your own. But the basic idea is that you have your progressbar's visibility bound to a variable, then you update that variable:

- when you launch the thread, to make it visible (using the `IsIndeterminate` property is useful since there's no real way to do percentages for a SQL query)
- when the thread finishes, to hide the progress bar.

In this way, you get the animated progress bar while the query is running.

You can set the mouse cursor to busy/arrow in the same way.

Comment: The reason I used the select *, is because the columns are only 12 the ones I am already applying in the for loop. there are no other columns in that table. since you are only experience with WPF. is there another guy that can help me with my problem. I need someone that can help with C# windows forms.